# Chi-square and R: Calculate matrix of statistical significances between results

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, p-value, matrix

First of all, I would like to apologize if this is an duplicate of an earlier question. I find it hard to believe that I am the first person to ever have this sort of problem, but I am so far out of my comfort zone that I do not really know what to search for (I have tried of course).

Me and my partner are a doing bachelor thesis, where a part of it have been creating an artefact in the domain of *information retrieval* and *natural language processing*. We have run a series of experiments with this artefact with several components or flags activated. In total, 32 experiments were conducted since five different flags were set on of off in all possible permutations ($5^2 = 32$). Originally, we would have thought that we should only test if any result was statistically significant compared to the setting were all flags were disabled. Our supervisor told us however that we should compare all results to each other, to see which of the flags would generate a statistically significant difference to each other.

Since this would make 496 comparisons ($31^2/2$), this is far more than what could be done by hand. Our supervisor recommended using R or pystat for simplifying the task. We have however no previous experience of either of these, all tough getting into R didn't seem to complicated, but we still don't know how to get the requested data.

Our current results from the experiments are in the following form (not all experiments);

```
            True Positives  False Positives False Negatives True Negatives
No Flags    174             879             2541            13224
E           303             2051            2412            12052
EF          301             1955            2414            12148
F           219             1211            2496            12892
S           224             1332            2491            12771
SE          304             2112            2411            11991
```

We want to see if certain flags yields an improvements in [F1-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) over others, in other words, if *true positives* increases and *false positives* and *false negatives* decreases. When calculating out F-Score, we use an unweighted F1-score were [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) are equally weighted

I have come as far as exporting the results into a CSV file and loading the file in a R script, but I do not know how to process it from there. How would we go about this?

It can be worth mentioning that we will display the results as their F1-scores, but as far as we understand we cannot compute statistical significance directly on a F-score compared to an other F-score.

Comment: What is it that you want to compare between the conditions? BTW, with 32 conditions, all pairwise comparisons is $(N(N-1))/2 = 16*31 = 496$, not $32^2 = 1024$, you don't need to compare both A to B *and* B to A, and you *certainly* don't need to compare A to A.

Comment: No your of course right that if you do it by hand it will only be 496.

We want to see if there's an improvement when using a certain set of flags over another, in other words if *true positives* increases and *false positives* and *false negatives* decreases. What we measure is really a change in F1-score. I'll update my post shortly.

Comment: Rather than (or in addition to) the counts of true positives, false positives, etc., do you have predicted probabilities that the object is a member of the positive class & the object's true class status? If you only have these, do you weight them differently? That is, would a false positive be worse than a false negative or vice versa?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but we weight precision and recall equally. So having a false positive would have the same impact as having a false negative on our result.

Comment: Do you have predicted probabilities, or only hard classifications?

Comment: We have no predicted probabilities. I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what hard classifications mean? That it can only be in either category? If so yes.